# Both Skeleton tracking methods are correct in kinect?

Tags: c#, windows, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-interaction

I have using kinect SDK to develop a application in C# . Now i have a doubt for tracking skeleton .

I have 2 code , but there is 2 different approaches . I want to know both methods leads to same concepts ? or different ?

code 1 :

```
void Kinect_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (SkeletonFrame frame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
    {
       m_skeletons = new Skeleton[frame.SkeletonArrayLength];
       frame.CopySkeletonDataTo(m_skeletons);
    } 

     if(m_skeletons != null && m_skeletons.Length != 0)
     { 
         foreach (Skeleton skeleton in m_skeletons)
         {
            if (skeleton != null && skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                //doing some operations 
            }


          }

      }

}
```

now another tracking methods like :
code 2 :

```
void Kinect_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (SkeletonFrame frame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
    {
       m_skeletons = new Skeleton[frame.SkeletonArrayLength];
       frame.CopySkeletonDataTo(m_skeletons);
    } 

     if(m_skeletons != null && m_skeletons.Length != 0)
     { 
         foreach (Skeleton skeleton in m_skeletons.Where(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked))
          {

               //doing some operations 
          }

      }

}
```

is both `foreach (Skeleton skeleton in m_skeletons)` and the

```
foreach (Skeleton skeleton in m_skeletons.Where(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked))
```

are correct ? Is any difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are functionally equivalent.

The `.Where(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)` creates an enumerator that already incorporates the check. So your `foreach` will only iterate the elements for which the condition holds. In the other example, you do this explicitly with an `if` statement.